# Android VideoView - video plays after “Can't Play Video” error message

Tags: android, android-videoview

I'm trying to play different type of videos in Android VideoView but there is an strange behaviour occurs if the media is an unsupported like .wmv or .avi files.
.mp4 files play without error. but if the media type is an .wmv or .avi, VideoWiew shows “Can't Play Video” and after this message, video starts playing.

```
    videoView.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
            videoView.start();
        }
    });

    videoView.setOnErrorListener(new MediaPlayer.OnErrorListener() {

        public boolean onError(MediaPlayer mp, int what, int extra) {
            Toast.makeText(context, "Unable to Start Video(" +  media.getPath() + ")", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return true;
        }
    });
```

MediaPlayer  error code is what: 1 and extra: -2147483648 which indicates MEDIA_ERROR_UNKNOWN